# preserve the levels of an empty factor after adding a value

Tags: r, r-factor

This is a very basic question but I do not get the reason for the weird behavior (on top of my head). Could you please comment on the reason why the factor `var2` became a character vector after adding a value (`var2 <-c(var2, value)`)?

```
df <- data.frame(var1 = sample(LETTERS[1:5],100, replace = T))

for(i in seq(from = 1, to = 25, by = 5)){
  var2 <- factor(levels = unique(df$var1))
  str(var2)
  kIndices <- df %>% ungroup() %>% rowid_to_column() %>% group_by(var1) %>% 
    filter(n() > i) %>% ungroup() %>% select(rowid) %>% unlist(use.names = F)
  str(var2)
  for(j in kIndices){
    value <- sample(LETTERS[1:4],1)
    #value <- as.factor(value)
    var2 <-c(var2, value)
  }
  str(var2)
}
```

How could I preserve it after the addition? I meant after the first statement `var2 <- factor(levels = unique(df$var1))` there are 5 levels and it should be the case even after this `var2 <-c(var2, value)` statement, irrespective of how many values present in the latter statement.

Comment: I can only comment on how to preserve after addition: try `var2 <- factor(c(as.character(var2), value))`. Or you could just set it to factor at the end of the loop.

Comment: If you add all the levels beforehand, does that work (note I haven't tested the code)
` var2 <- factor(levels = c(unique(df$var1), LETTERS[1:4]))`

Comment: @juan That do not preserve the levels which I have defined earlier. In the first statement `var2 <- factor(levels = unique(df$var1))` it has 5 levels and after this `var2 <-c(var2, value)` I would want 5 levels only. But in the approach you have mentioned it gives 4 levels.

Comment: @FlorianGD It did not work either :(

Comment: @Prradep I misunderstood. Then you should be able to preserve the 5 levels by adding the same argument like so: `var2 <- factor(c(as.character(var2), value), levels=unique(df$var1))`